# Kafka consumer group is not consuming messages from all the consumers

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I created kafka topic with partitions and replication factor

[image]

Then I started producing messages, with my producer

[image]

I started two consumers with help of consumer groups parallely.

[image]

when I stopped one consumer, the other consumer starts working.

I'm suspecting that default configuration when I downloading kafka is misleading me.

I expect all my consumers need to receive messages concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

Two consumers within a group cannot read the same partition at once. You will need to verify records are written to both partitions and not batched together, which is the console producer default behavior for small record batches

Use GetOffsetShell tool to inspect how many offsets (approximately, number of records) each partition has. You can also use `kafka-consumer-groups` command to see lag for the group. If you see all partitions have zero lag, then you've consumed all the records in the topic with all consumers (take note that one partition may have a start and end offset of the same value, which GetOffsetShell would show as well, meaning that partition is empty, thereby explaining why only one consumer prints any data).

Comment: Thank you for responding. I have verified like you said. `C:\kafka\bin\windows>kafka-run-class.bat  kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test32
test32:0:6
test32:1:0`
  However only one partition is consuming all the messages not sure why ? and there is no lag in partitions 
`GROUP           TOPIC           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG              myfirstgroup    test32          0          6               6               0                myfirstgroup    test32          1          0               0               0  –`

Comment: It seems I figured out the issue, so the kafka has default batch size, once its reaches its size partition will change. starting from kafka2.4 the default partitioned has changed from round robin to sticky.  https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-producer-improvements-sticky-partitioner/

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka has the default batch size of 16384(bytes), once we start produce enough messages to fill that buffer size then it will change partition.

starting from kafka2.4 the default partitioned has changed from round robin to [sticky](https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-producer-improvements-sticky-partitioner/)

So I override the property like this it worked.

`C:\kafka\bin\windows>kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list localhost:9092 --batch-size=1 --topic test32`

and we can also produce messages to a particular partition by specifying partitions ids like below:

`C:\kafka\bin\windows>kafka-console-producer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test32 -property "parse.key=true" -property "key.separator=:"`

`0:test`
`1:test2`

where `0` and `1` are the partition ids and `test`, `test2` are values.

[image]

Comment: Note: batch.size is measured in bytes, not records. The string `"test"` for example is larger than 1 byte